# MVC 3 DataAnnotations: Not allow HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

Is there anyway to use DataAnnotations in MVC 3 to not allow HTML is used in a textbox?
I see a way to allow using HTML (AllowHTMLAttribute) but what if i dont want the user to type any HTML in the textbox and want to warning him?

Thanks :)

Comment: HTML is not allowed by default.

Comment: yup i know that, but i want to detect it and warning the user not to type it in the textbox :)

Comment: Depends on where you want to detect it. The property is located on the `ControllerBase` object, and called `ValidateRequest`, and is set pr. Request basis. If the property is `True`, `ValidateRequest(HttpRequestBase request)` is called on the `ControllerActionInvoker`, which in turns calls `ValidateInput()` on the request object.

Comment: Besides marking an answer as accepted, you may want to "vote-up" the answers and comments that helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to write a custom RegularExpressionAttribute ... something like this:

```
public class DisallowHTMLAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public DisallowHTMLAttribute()
        : base(@"</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:"".*?""|'.*?'|[^'"">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>")
    {
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {

        return String.Format("The field {0} cannot contain html tags", name);

    }
}
```

You must register the adapter to enable client side validation, so in Application_Start in Global.asax add this line of code:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(DisallowHTMLAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
```

And in your model, add the attribute to the properties you want to disallow html tags, like this:

```
[DisallowHTML]
public string SomeProperty{ get; set; }
```

Comment: First thanks for the question, but there's something wrong with ur code, the DisallowHTMLAttribute now disable me to submit a text, but HTML, it mean the code allow only HTML to submit lol

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because a RegularExpressionAttribute is valid when it matches the regular expression.  To get this to work just extend ValidationAttribute and override the IsValid method.  The regular expression here still isn't very good because it won't detect broken html.

Comment: Could someone post a regexp that will match even broken html tags? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may set  `[ValidateInput(true)]` on controller action

Answer (score 0):

Escaping user's text when displaying it may be enough. What if the user wants to post a HTML/XML sample?

<%: Model.UsersContent %>

Comment: so what if i want to care about the title of a thread when user posting it, i just want it as  text normally

Comment: I don't know what the website is about. But what if a user want to create a title like "Is a <span> more appropriate than a <div> in my code?". Or even "Encoding of characters < and > with UTF-8"? 
Using angled brackets does not always mean HTML. What about detecting the presence of brackets and warn the user HTML won't be interpreted?

Answer (score 0):

Im using this data annotation with a regular expression to check for html tags

```
public class DisallowHTMLAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public DisallowHTMLAttribute()
        : base(@"[^<>&]*")
    {
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format("The field {0} cannot contain html tags", name);
    }
}
```

In my model:

```
    [Required]
    [DisallowHTML]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
```