# How do I handle a HttpRequestValidationException and return a meaningful error using AddModelError?

Tags: model-view-controller, validation, exception, request, modelstate

I would like to handle **HttpRequestValidationExceptions** (e.g. when html is inserted into form fields) and return the user back to the page after submission with a meaningful error to highlight the problem.

For example, on a login page, if the user types some invalid characters into the username field, then I would like to catch the **HttpRequestValidationException** and return the user to the login page with the username field highlighted.

I can catch the error in a class inheriting from **HandleErrorAttribute** using the **OnException** method.

Is there a way from here (or any other way) that I can get the **Controller** **ModelState** to add the error?

*Note: I do not want to turn validation off or redirect to an error page.*

e.g.:

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Exception is HttpRequestValidationException)
        {
            ModelStateDictionary ModelState = <...>
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Invalid chars");
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            HttpContextBase HttpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
            HttpContext.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Request.Path);

            return;
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of capturing and handling the `HttpRequestValidationException`, you could decorate your model's properties with the [`[AllowHtml]` data annotation](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/16/AllowHtmlAttributeASPNETMVC3.aspx) and your own custom [data annotation](http://rachelappel.com/asp-net-mvc/how-data-annotations-for-asp-net-mvc-validation-work/), which contains the validation rules you require. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6313936/292230) for a good example.

Your model's properties may look like this:

```
[AllowHtml]
[DisallowHtml]
public string SomeProperty{ get; set; }
```

Which looks a bit silly, but so far it's the cleanest solution I've encountered.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely looks like they cleanest way forward for me.  I'll be looking at the sample answer you pointed me to.